# bind variable error in stored procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

Here is my procedure code :

```
create or replace Procedure SP_CUSTOMER_PRODUCT_QRY
   ( PARENT_PARTYID IN varchar2,PRODUCT_ID IN varchar2,PRODUCT_STATUS IN varchar2,PAGING  IN varchar2,OFFSET IN varchar2,LIST_OF_PARTIES OUT VARCHAR2 )
AS
V_SQL_WHERE varchar2(10000):= null;
V_SQL varchar2(10000):='SELECT PARTYID FROM TABLE1';
    V_check varchar2(10000) := '' ;
BEGIN

    IF(PARENT_PARTYID IS NOT NULL) THEN
      V_SQL_WHERE := V_SQL_WHERE || ' PARENT_PARTYID=:1';
    END IF; 

    IF(PRODUCT_ID IS NOT NULL) THEN

      IF (V_SQL_WHERE is not null) THEN 
        V_SQL_WHERE := V_SQL_WHERE || ' AND ';
      END IF;

      V_SQL_WHERE := V_SQL_WHERE || ' PRODUCT_ID=:2';
    END IF; 

    IF(PRODUCT_STATUS IS NOT NULL) THEN

      IF (V_SQL_WHERE is not null) THEN 
         V_SQL_WHERE := V_SQL_WHERE || ' AND ';
      END IF; 
      V_SQL_WHERE := V_SQL_WHERE || ' PRODUCT_STATUS=:3';

    END IF; 

    IF (V_SQL_WHERE is not null) then
      V_SQL := V_SQL || ' WHERE ' || V_SQL_WHERE;
    end if;


    dbms_output.put_line(V_SQL);
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE V_SQL INTO LIST_OF_PARTIES;
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
      V_check:= '' ;
    END;
```

I have used bind variables ,unable to understand the issue.Is it mandatory to bind all parameters even if they are not used in procedure
When I am passing any input I am getting error as 
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01008: not all variables bound

Answer (score 0):

In this case there is no need for using dynamic plsql. Try to do this this way:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_CUSTOMER_PRODUCT_QRY
   ( P_PARENT_PARTYID IN VARCHAR2,
     P_PRODUCT_ID IN VARCHAR2,
     P_PRODUCT_STATUS IN VARCHAR2,
     P_PAGING  IN VARCHAR2,
     P_OFFSET IN VARCHAR2,
     P_LIST_OF_PARTIES OUT VARCHAR2 )
AS
   CURSOR CUR_PARTYID
   IS
   SELECT PARTYID 
   FROM TABLE1
   WHERE (P_PARENT_PARTYID IS NULL 
        OR PARENT_PARTYID = P_PARENT_PARTYID)
        AND (P_PRODUCT_ID IS NULL
        OR PRODUCT_ID = P_PRODUCT_ID)
        AND (P_PRODUCT_STATUS IS NULL
        OR PRODUCT_STATUS = P_PRODUCT_STATUS);
BEGIN

    OPEN  CUR_PARTYID;
    FETCH CUR_PARTYID INTO P_LIST_OF_PARTIES;
    CLOSE CUR_PARTYID;

END;
/
```

Answer (score -1):

You need the "using" clause with your execute immediate for the 3 variables in the where clause.

for example:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DELETE FROM dept WHERE deptno = :num' USING dept_id;
```

Comment: thanks wieseman ,however I would like to know what is the best way of writing it,using clause will vary depending on the input parameters received to the procedure.Should i again use if clause for the same as well. wht is the best practice for this ?

Comment: Best way is to avoid dynamic sql in this case. It is not necessary. You are able to solve this problem with single simple cursor.